# Prove: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^{3/2}}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to prove the convergence of the first series:

1)$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^{3}}$

2) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^{1/2}}$

3)$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^{3/2}}$

I have proved the convergence of  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^{2}}$ and the divergence of  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n}$ . I think that for 1) I can use the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^{2}}$ and the compairson criterion (due to $\frac1{n^3}<\frac1{n^2}$) to conclude that converges, Is it correct?
And for 2) I can use a similar argument.

The problem is for 3) Any idea?

I can only use the Cauchy criterion or the convergence of another similar series.

Comment: Do you know integral test?

Comment: I can use only the Cauchy criterion or the convergence of another similar series.

Comment: yes you can prove that the series in 2) diverges by comparing it to the Harmonic series.

Comment: For the third series, can you use *Cauchy's condensation test*?